# JSON or SimpleJSON and Python with Twython

Tags: json, python-2.7, simplejson, twython

I'm a newbie to Python and JSON as well. I installed twython to "speak" to the Twitter API. I use Python 2.7 on a mac.

I would like to get my mentions through the API. The program should identify the Twitter user who mentioned me.

I try:

```
t = Twython(...)
men = t.get_mentions_timeline()
```

The user is mentioned once, print men shows a lot of stuff like this:

```
[{u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': .... u'Sun May 26 09:18:55 +0000 2013', u'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None, u'place': None}]
```

Somewhere in this stuff I see all the things I would like to extract from the response.

How can I extract the `screen_name`?

I'm quite confused with `json.dumps` or `json.loads` - shall I work with `json` or `simplejson`?

Comment: I've got the solution - only one for: 
    
for mention in men:
 mu = mention ['user'] 
 tweetid = mention ['id']
 usern = mu['screen_name']
 print tweetid 
 print usern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `json` (or `simplejson`, which is the exact same library; it was renamed when bundled with Python); the `Twython` library already decoded everything from JSON for you.

You got a list from the API, each entry is a `dict`; each such dictionary is a Tweet. You can see what is contained in the [Twitter API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets). Loop over that list; some items are dictionaries or lists themselves:

```
for mention in men:
    print mention['user']['screen_name']
    if mention['contributors']:
        print [con['screen_name'] for con in mention['contributors']]
```

To figure out the full structure, use `pprint.pprint()` to print a structured version:

```
import pprint

pprint.pprint(men)
```

which will make it easier for you to figure out what you can loop over, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error:
    KeyError: 'screen_name'

perhaps I should mention that screen_name is part of the entities

Looks like this:

u'entities': {u'symbols': [], 
 u'user_mentions': [{u'id': 1457484992, 
 u'indices': [0, 8], 
 u'id_str': u'1457484992', 
 u'screen_name': u'CyclopT', ....

Comment: @hildwin: I had an error in an earlier edit; can you tell me what you used? Use the `pprint` trick to figure out what is a list and what is a dictionary.

Comment: The second loop won't work. The structure is: 

` u'user': {u'screen_name': u'NAME'

(more stuff)

}`

Comment: @hildwin: Right, I was homing in on the `contributors` key (which was `None` in your first example, so that wouldn't work). The `user` key *also* has a `screen_name` key. The API link I pointed to includes a link for the `user` key, pointing to the [Users page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/users). Updated the answer to show that *and* the contributors (if any).